# Showing multiple tables in one SQL Server view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have ten table-valued functions that return tables with the same layouts. I want to show the output of all ten functions in a view in SQL Server 2005.

When I try like this in the view design...

```
select col1, col2... coln from dbo.tableFunc1
Union
select col1, col2... coln from dbo.tableFunc2
```

I get the message:

> *Views containing Unions cannot be represented graphically in the Grid and Diagram panes.*

Is there any way to aggregate all of these functions right in the view or do I have to write an additional function to aggregate the functions and then just view the output of the aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a view for multiple functions?  Why not just make the views from the tables doing the logic of the functions?  EG: instead of

```
select col1, col2
from dbo.tablefunc1
union
select col1, col2
from dbo.tablefunc2
```

do

```
Select col1, col2
from tableforfunc1 1
   join tableforfunc2 2 on 1.id = 2.id
union
Select col1, col2
from tablefunc2
```

If that is too difficult due to logic in the creation of the table functions, why not just remake a larger table function or proc then with the combination of all objects?

I tried this in SQL Server 2012 with some basic test table functions and they worked so I wonder if this is a limitation of 2005.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do anything!

Re-read the warning message, it's just telling you that this view cannot be represented graphically. It doesn't mean your view is invalid, all you need to do is ignore the message and continue working. Your view will still be created and it can still be used like any other view.